# Excel macro, read cell with Persian text

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I have created a simple excel worksheet.

This is my macro code:

```
Sub MyMacro()
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    A$ = Cells(1, 1)
    MsgBox (A$)
End Sub
```

It works correct, if Cell 1,1 contains an English word, or numbers.

But when I put some Persian/Arabic text into Cell 1,1 (example: `سلام` ) and run macro, macro shows `????`. (It shows a `?` instead of each Persian character)

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the Windows API message box instead, which should display most encoding types

eg, this goes into a `MODULE`

```
Option Explicit

#If Win64 Then
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function User32MsgBox Lib "user32" Alias "MessageBoxW" _
        (Optional ByVal hWnd As Long, Optional ByVal Prompt As Long, _
        Optional ByVal Title As Long, Optional ByVal Buttons As Long) As Long

#Else
    Private Declare Function User32MsgBox Lib "user32" Alias "MessageBoxW" _
        (Optional ByVal hWnd As Long, Optional ByVal Prompt As Long, _
        Optional ByVal Title As Long, Optional ByVal Buttons As Long) As Long

#End If


Public Function MessageBoxW(cPrompt As String, _
    Optional cButtons As VbMsgBoxStyle = vbOKOnly, _
    Optional cTitle As String) As Long

    MessageBoxW = User32MsgBox(0, StrPtr(cPrompt), StrPtr(cTitle), cButtons)
    '*****Probably need to convert StrPtr to 32bit long on 64bit - see next line
    'MessageBoxW = User32MsgBox(0, cLng(StrPtr(cPrompt)), CLng(StrPtr(cTitle)), cButtons)

End Function



Sub MyMacro()
Dim txt As String
    txt = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1).Value
    MessageBoxW (txt)
End Sub
```

I don't have a 64bit machine with me at the moment so you may need to convert the StrPtr to 32bit Long on a 64bit machine

Comment: Info on amending API calls in VBA on 64-bit systems is at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee691831.aspx#odc_office2010_Compatibility32bit64bit_ApplicationProgrammingInterfaceCompatibility

Comment: Where in the code should I paste this piece of code?